# PHP : Grouping array in for-each loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, sum

I have an array like this :

```
array(2) {
  ["currency"]=>
    string(7) "bitcoin"
  ["Totalcs"]=>
   string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  ["currency"]=>
    string(8) "ethereum"
  ["Totalcs"]=>
   string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  ["currency"]=>
    string(8) "ethereum"
  ["Totalcs"]=>
   string(1) "1"
}
```

I want to group this array like this :

```
array(2) {
 ["currency"]=>
   string(7) "bitcoin"
 ["Totalcs"]=>
   string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
 ["currency"]=>
   string(8) "ethereum"
 ["Totalcs"]=>
   string(1) "2"
 }
```

I tried many ways, but didn't work anyone ....please help me

Comment: try array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR); for more visit http://php.net/language.operators.array

Comment: Please, share code attempt, one at least.

Comment: Was really unclear until I have noticed u are increasing count...... as sanjit specified try array unique.

Comment: alice ,, yup ......

Comment: @Irfan that is an unsuitable dupe link.  There is no summing going on there.  Probably 100 other/better links to find.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I am assuming group by functionality on array, therefore I was marked, may be It is wrong..

Comment: @VishnuGopinath  i have changed my solution so please have a look to the current edited solution (`I HAVE USED isset() INSIDE foreach()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `foreach()` with new array creation will do the job:-

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($array as $arr){

  $final_array[$arr['currency']]['currency'] = $arr['currency'];
  $final_array[$arr['currency']]['Totalcs'] = (isset($final_array[$arr['currency']]['Totalcs']))? $final_array[$arr['currency']]['Totalcs']+$arr['Totalcs'] : $arr['Totalcs'];

}

$final_array = array_values($final_array);

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/957322

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign temporary keys as you iterate your input array.  This method will not perform any unnecessary value overwrites.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/paqNF))

```
$array=[
    ['currency'=>'bitcoin','Totalcs'=>'1'],
    ['currency'=>'ethereum','Totalcs'=>'1'],
    ['currency'=>'ethereum','Totalcs'=>'1']
];
foreach($array as $row){  // iterate all rows
    if(!isset($result[$row['currency']])){  // if first occurrence of currency...
        $result[$row['currency']]=$row;     // save the full row with currency as the temporary key
    }else{                                    // if not the first occurrence of currency...
        $result[$row['currency']]['Totalcs']+=$row['Totalcs'];  // add Totalcs value
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'currency' => 'bitcoin',
    'Totalcs' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'currency' => 'ethereum',
    'Totalcs' => 2,
  ),
)
```